# The image is distorted after getting it from Camera Intent

Tags: android, kotlin

I am uploading an image from camera. Then from intent's extra bundle I am getting the bitmap. However, the bitmap is resulting in a very distorted image.

```
  UPLOAD_FROM_CAMERA -> {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data?.extras != null) {
                        getImageUri(
                            requireContext(),
                            data.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
                        )?.let { it1 ->
                            launchImageCrop(
                                it1
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    fun getImageUri(inContext: Context, inImage: Bitmap): Uri? {
       val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
       inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes)
       val path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
        inContext.contentResolver,
        inImage,
        "Title",
        null
        )


    return Uri.parse(path ?: "")
}

   private fun launchImageCrop(uri: Uri) {
    CropImage.activity(uri)
        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
        .setAspectRatio(1080, 1080)
        .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.RECTANGLE)
        .start(requireContext(), this)
}
```

First I thought the reason of distortion to be compression to URI. However, when I set the bitmap to imageView(without converting it to URI), it is still distorted. So, the problem must be in bitmap that is coming from intent. What would you suggest? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You only get a thumbnail of the original image with the camera intent you use.  A thumbnail bitmap with very low resolution. Use the camera intent in such a way that a full image file is created by the camera app.

Comment: @blackapps How can I do that?